# Setting Content-Type and Status-Code in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, http-status-code-404, content-type, page-directives

Its a two part question.
Part 1: I want to set the `content-type` of jsp page depending on the `Accept` header for which I'm doing

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(header['accept'], 'xml')}">
    <c:set var="contentType" value="application/xml;charset=UTF-8"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${fn:contains(header['accept'], 'json')}">
    <c:set var="contentType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
</c:if>
<jsp:directive.page contentType='${contentType}'/>
```

for which I get response like [image: this.]
I also tried
`<c:set target="${pageContext.response}" property="ContentType" value="${contentType}"/>`
for which I got
`Invalid property in &lt;set&gt;:  "ContentType"`
My other EL expression are getting evaluated properly so I've already my experiment with `isELIgnored` attribute. I don't want to use scriptlet tags either.
Part 2: I want to set `status code` dynamically without the help of scriptlet tag from **JSP page only.**
Currently I'm doing
`<% response.setStatus(200) %>`
I'm aware it can be set in a `servlet` or a `filter` but I want it to be set from a `jsp` page or via `custom` tag.Kindly guide me through this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**
I stumbled upon my previous work in which I've used `setAttribute()` so I tried this and it worked so this is how it can be done.
For both the part create a custom tag by extending a `BodyTagSupport` in which we can get `HttpServletResponse` object this way:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) pageContext.getResponse();
```

Once you've the `response` object you can easily set the `Content-Type` and `status code`